# Subshells not working

Tags: subshell

I want to run several commands in parallel, but I have no idea why the following code piece does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
( ping 8.8.8.8 )
( ping 192.168.0.1 )
```

It completely ignores the second ping command. Why is that so?

Edit: OK, now I know that you can run them in parallel by doing `&`.

```
ping 8.8.8.8 & ping 192.168.0.1
```

But why did the above code piece not work?

Comment: the first ping doesn't end by itself, so the 2nd command won't run until you kill the first ping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subshell is not forking by default and you also would have to use `&` to send it to the background to execute the second subshell without waiting for the first subshell to end.

e.g.

```
ping 8.8.8.8 & ping 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: In most shells, a subshell forks and in any case, subshell or not, the shell will fork a process to execute that `ping` command in a separate process as there's no shell that I know that has `ping` as a builtin command. But the point here is that the shell will **wait** for the termination of that process. `&` doesn't make a difference whether the shell forks or not (it forks with and without `&`) but whether the shell will wait or not for that process to finish before carrying on with the rest of the script.